# savefig PGF - RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer

Tags: python, matplotlib, pgf

I'm trying to save a figure in pyplot with tight margins.

The following code works perfectly with a PDF output:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(1)
plt.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

But not with PGF output

```
plt.savefig('test.pgf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

as it returns `RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer`.

Why is this happening and is there a way to work around it?

matplotlib 1.3.0rc2 on Ubuntu 13.04

```
python -c "from matplotlib import pyplot as plt; plt.plot(1); plt.savefig('test.pgf', bbox_inches='tight');"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "PYTHONPATH/matplotlib-1.3.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 561, in savefig
    return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "PYTHONPATH/matplotlib-1.3.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1410, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "PYTHONPATH/matplotlib-1.3.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 161, in print_figure
    FigureCanvasAgg.print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "PYTHONPATH/matplotlib-1.3.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2169, in print_figure
    bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)
  File "PYTHONPATH/matplotlib-1.3.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1551, in get_tightbbox
    bb.append(ax.get_tightbbox(renderer))
  File "PYTHONPATH/matplotlib-1.3.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axes.py", line 9153, in get_tightbbox
    bb_xaxis = self.xaxis.get_tightbbox(renderer)
  File "PYTHONPATH/matplotlib-1.3.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1055, in get_tightbbox
    renderer)
  File "PYTHONPATH/matplotlib-1.3.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1038, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "PYTHONPATH/matplotlib-1.3.0rc2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/text.py", line 751, in get_window_extent
    raise RuntimeError('Cannot get window extent w/o renderer')
RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer
```

Comment: Does this also happen with the final release?  If so, please report this as a bug.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise it was out. Yes, it happens with 1.3.0 final too. I shall report it now.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2342

Comment: fixed upstream, should be included in the next bugfix release

Answer (score 1):

By the way, there is a workaround. Normally the extent of PGF/TikZ images is adjusted automatically so it matches the drawing. For preserving the figure size intended by matplotlib, these lines are added to the output:

```
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{8.000000in}{6.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{use as bounding box}%
```

If you remove these lines at the very top from the PGF output you should get rid of any additional space around the figure.

Using `plt.tight_layout()`, or better `plt.figure(tight_layout=True)` in version 1.3, is another way to do that (which works perfectly with PGF and PGF->PDF), although it is a bit different. It recalculates the figure's layout so it fits to the given figure size. I usually prefer that method because it also eliminates problems like overlapping text elements.

Comment: I tried adding ```plt.figure(tight_layout=True)``` to my code but it wouldn't do anything - where exactly should I add it? right before savefig()?

Comment: `plt.figure` creates a new figure, which matplotlib implicitly does when you start plotting without creating a figure. You have to put that call before adding any plots to the figure.
`plt.tight_layout()` on the other hand is best placed right before `savefig`

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything - all I get is this http://oi41.tinypic.com/2nixulx.jpg (doesn't seem very tight)

Comment: The default padding for tight layout is not zero. Try `plt.tight_layout(pad=0)` or `plt.figure(tight_layout={"pad": 0})`.

Comment: Adding that code still does not change the graphic I linked to above.

Comment: never mind, solved it, I was specifying tight_layout in too many places :) many thanks for your assistance!